# Show order of letters in alphabet as they appear

Tags: java, arrays

I have a key which is in the form of a string, for example "security", and I'd like to create an array that shows the order of each letter in the alphabet, in the place of the letter. So for example, for the word "security", that array would be `[5, 2, 1, 7, 4, 3, 6, 8]` (assuming I'm not starting from zero).

This is what I have tried, but it doesn't output what I need:

```
String key = "Security";

key = key.toLowerCase();

String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(alphabet.indexOf(key.charAt(i)) + " ");
}
```

Output:

```
18 4 2 20 17 8 19 24
```

By the way, I didn't put the output in an array because the output is not what I want.

Any suggestions? I'm sure this is very easy for most programmers, but I'm new to Java programming so it's hard for me.

Comment: You can solve it with a similar approach. Instead of your "alphabet" variable change that string into the sorted version of your key.

Comment: You're currently outputting the absolute positions in the alphabet (starting at 0 for "a"). You now need to sort based on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little tweak to your `alphabet` should do:

```
    String key = "Security".toLowerCase();
    String alphabet =
            // Split the key into characters.
            Arrays.stream(key.split(""))
            // Sort it.
            .sorted()
            // Put it back together into a String again.
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(alphabet.indexOf(key.charAt(i)) + 1 + " ");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked and your comments were helpful in my understanding of the solution. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can simply sort your own word by converting it to char array, sort and back to String.

```
String key = "Security";
key = key.toLowerCase();

char[] charArray = key.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(charArray);

key = new String(charArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get char array from your string, sort it, and for each char in string find corresponding index in sorted char array.

```
String key = "Security";
key = key.toLowerCase();

char letters[] = key.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(letters);    // 'c' 'e' 'i' 'r' 's' 't' 'u' 'y'

for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(letters, key.charAt(i));
    System.out.format("%d ", index + 1);
}
```